# SuggestRequestBuilder.java / org.elasticsearch.action.suggest is missing

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I am trying to upgrade Elasticsearch spring boot project from 1.5.7 to 2.2.1. Only dependency(related to elastic search) I have in my project is spring-data-Elasticsearch. But as few of the classes like `SuggestRequestBuilder` is missing/deprecated my build is getting failed. I checked in google as well couldn't find any suitable alternative. Can anyone help me to find the alternative way to use these `suggestRequestBuilder`, `suggestionResponse`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With spring-boot 2.3.1 and spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch I'm using `Suggest*` classes from `org.elasticsearch.search.suggest.*` package.

**Example:**

There are some products added to ES index:

```
{
    "_index": "products",
    "_id": "WtYOV3MBurwvUvNLpjxM",
    "_source": {
        "productName": "Hammer",
        "available": true
    }
},
{
    "_index": "products",
    "_id": "XtYdV3MBurwvUvNLXjzO",
    "_source": {
        "productName": "Hammer with handle",
        "available": true
    }
}
```

And now I wan't to make a suggestion for a word 'hamer' based on `productName` field. This is the complete code to find the correct suggestion:

```
import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest;
import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RequestOptions;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient;
import org.elasticsearch.search.builder.SearchSourceBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.search.suggest.Suggest;
import org.elasticsearch.search.suggest.SuggestBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.search.suggest.SuggestBuilders;
import org.elasticsearch.search.suggest.SuggestionBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.search.suggest.term.TermSuggestion;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.ClientConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.RestClients;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;    
import ...;

@Component
public class ProductService {

  private static final Logger logger = getLogger(ProductService.class);

  public void suggestProducts() {

    ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration =
        ClientConfiguration.builder().connectedTo("localhost:9200").build();
    RestHighLevelClient client = RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();

    SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    SuggestionBuilder termSuggestionBuilder =
        SuggestBuilders.termSuggestion("productName").text("Hamer");
    SuggestBuilder suggestBuilder = new SuggestBuilder();
    suggestBuilder.addSuggestion("suggest_product", termSuggestionBuilder);
    searchSourceBuilder.suggest(suggestBuilder);

    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
    searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
    SearchResponse searchResponse;
    try {
      searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
      Suggest suggest = searchResponse.getSuggest();
      TermSuggestion termSuggestion = suggest.getSuggestion("suggest_product");
      for (TermSuggestion.Entry entry : termSuggestion.getEntries()) {
        for (TermSuggestion.Entry.Option option : entry) {
          String suggestText = option.getText().string();
          logger.info(suggestText);
        }
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

And this prints the correct result: "hammer". Of course there are other types of suggestions available (`termSuggestion`, `completionSuggestion`, `phraseSuggestion`) and you can flexibly adjust the parameters of the query.